# How to save node form data in form_values using drupal_execute

Tags: 6

I want to save `$form_values` in the session table in the submit handler when a node type (eg page) is saved.

How can I reuse this `$form_values` to create this node again using `drupal_execute` after some time (say tomorrow)?

I've tried creating it but it isn't working out:

```
function abcdonations_entry() {
  if (isset($_SESSION['form_id'])) {
    $fs = $_SESSION['form_id'];
    $form_id = $fs['values']['form_id'];
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $node = array('type' => 'person');
    drupal_execute($form_id, $fs,(object)$node);
    print "Written successfully";  
  }
}
```

Then I save it in this function:

```
function anu_general_form_person_node_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $_SESSION['form_id'] = $form_state;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right you basically want to clone a node later? If this is the case than you can just:

```
$nid = $the_nid_of_the_old_node;  //get the $nid of the old node
$new_node = node_load($nid);      //load the old node object
$new_node->nid = NULL;            //unset nid to tell node_save that this is a new node
// do what ever you need to the new node
node_save($new_node);             //save the new node
```

That should do it.

Comment: Have you tried the function [confirm_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/confirm_form/6)? This basically redirects the user (on submission) to a confirmation page where you can show him the duplicated nodes (if any).

Comment: Isn't what [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) is for? I have to say that I never tried this but it should work by altering the form like this. And, may I say, it's a clean solution because you can do it in your own custom module. You don't have to mess with Drupal's core.

Comment: hook_form_alter isn't for this.

Comment: @Aga Altering a form is exactly what `hook_form_alter` is for. Forms are not classes in Drupal and as such don't have a constructor so I think there's some confusion here. `hook_form_alter` works fine to alter multistep forms (even those that live in core), I've done it many times

Comment: @Clive then please tell me how to use confirm_form to ask for confirmation when user saves a page node for example. That is any form whose form construction code lies in the Drupal core.

Comment: @Aga I didn't say you can use `confirm_form`. `hook_form_alter()` is user to alter the form. You could very easily alter the node form to ask for confirmation on save, but that doesn't mean using `confirm_form` you'd need to roll your own logic

Comment: I don't know if `confirm_form` would really help you as it only adds some default confirmation structure to your form but as @Clive said you could use multistep forms. Take a look at [this](http://www.andrewyager.com/blog/2008-06-03/drupal-6-multistep-forms) link. And you can use multistep form only if there is duplicated content for the current node. To hook into the node processing immediately after the user submitted changes on it you could use [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)(more precisely $op:validate)

Comment: @AgA are you also looking solution for the same problem?